# How to create light center video with images

Tags: ffmpeg

how to create video light center with images.png into video. See image.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is called the vignette effect and ffmpeg has a namesake filter for it.

```
ffmpeg -i video -vf vignette output
```

You can adjust the falloff using the angle parameter

```
ffmpeg -i video -vf vignette=angle=PI/4 output
```

---

If you want to use an image as a mask,

```
ffmpeg -i video -loop 1 -i image -filter_complex \
       "[1][0]blend=c0_mode=multiply:shortest=1" output.mp4
```

Image resolution should be the same as the video.

Comment: i want use picture.jpg make cover face for video.mp4

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: I want using image http://i.imgur.com/nteHKpx.jpg mist up video

Comment: Still not clear. Can you show a result?

Comment: Example here:
http://i.imgur.com/yr0oJ9v.jpg

Comment: Added command for image.

Comment: error
[swscaler @ 00000000012f5500] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[Parsed_blend_0 @ 0000000001269e80] First input link top parameters (size 960x540, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding second input link bottom parameters (1280x720, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_blend_0 @ 0000000001269e80] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_blend_0
Error configuring complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: Resolution should be same.

Comment: i have resize resolution same, but render video not working

Comment: What happens? Show command and result.

Comment: command here
ffmpeg -i ga.mp4 -loop 1 -i 123.jpg -filter_complex "[0][1]blend=c0_mode=multiply:shortest=1" 99.mp4

Comment: And i want question i'm using filter_audio code:
-af "pan=stereo|c0<c0+0*c1|c1<c0+0*c1,aeval=val(1)|-val(1),volume=1.5" -vcodec libx264 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100
But on Mobile, video no sound please help me fix it
Thank you very mich Mulvya

Comment: Blend input is `[1][0]`, not `[0][1]`. For audio, try `-acodec aac`

Comment: Blend is working but audio -acodec aac not work

Comment: Which mobile and OS?

Comment: work on android but not work on ios

Comment: please help me fix sound